# Flutter/Dart Date Set firstDayOfTheweek as Sunday

Tags: flutter, dart

By default, Monday is set as the first day of the week. The middle east region, Sunday is considered the first day of the week.

```
var now = DateTime.now(); 
print("todays date is $now");

print("week day is: ${now.weekday}");

 // todays date is 2020-09-13 12:20:02.417210
 // week day is: 7
```

since today is Sunday, I want the now.weekday should return as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.weekday` returns an integer in the range 1..7 that corresponds to the `DateTime` constants of `monday`, `tuesday`, etc.  The constants are assigned *internal values* with Monday as the smallest value, but whether you actually treat Monday as the first day of the week is completely up to you.

But if it's easier for you to have weekday values assigned where the value for Sunday is less than the value for Monday, you could just do:

```dart
int getAdjustedWeekday(DateTime dateTime) => dateTime.weekday % 7;
```

And now `getAdjustedWeekday` will return 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so on.

If you need values starting from 1 instead of 0, then just add 1:

```dart
int getAdjustedWeekday(DateTime dateTime) => 1 + dateTime.weekday % 7;
```

Note that you would not be able to use the existing `DateTime.sunday`, `DateTime.monday`, etc. constants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert like below.

```
var now = DateTime.now();
final now1 = DateFormat("EEEE").format(DateTime.parse(now.toString()));

print("todays date is $now1");
```

Or if you need int of day then go like below

Declare  a `day`

```
final day = now1 == "Sunday"
    ? 1
    : now1 == "Monday"
        ? 2
        : now1 == "Tuesday"
            ? 3
            : now1 == "Wednesday"
                ? 4
                : now1 == "Thursday" ? 5 : now1 == "Friday" ? 6 : 7;
```

And call from widget.

```
print(day);
```

Comment: DateFormat is in which package ??